# Can an Italian non-EU resident obtain a tourist visa to travel to USA?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, italy, proof-provenance-of-funds

I would like to invite my friend who is a Nigerian living in Italy and holding a Italian residency (permesso di soggiorno) to visit me in USA. Can an Italian resident (permesso di soggiorno) obtain a tourist visa to travel to USA? What if he is not working? I would be the one sponsoring his trip. Would he be allowed to visit?

Answer (score 8):

He can apply, having a job is not a requirement.

But he is not in a good position to get a visa.  Several points, not all will weigh as strongly, but there might be more still.

- He is a single male, who has left his home country for a lenghty stay abroad;
- This amplifies that he may have no or few ties back home to return to;
- He is coming from a country with a tradition of visa abuse, thus making it harder for the genuine people to get visa;
- He is not leading an independent life... he does not have the resources to sponsor himself. This heightens his risk profile.

I do not say that he is/will do any of these things, it is what the people granting visa will see and fear.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. I agree. I guess it's a chance we have to take.